# Django: Different form fields for different users or administrators?

Tags: django, django-forms

This question is about presenting input to different users for the same page. Should I create a single catch all Form and hide different fields? Or should I use entirely different Forms for different users? Or perhaps another option?

Comment: If the fields that the 2 different types of users have to enter are not very similar then I would use two separate forms and check for the type of user in the views then pass the form for that specific type of user to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hide forms in the 'html' way, if that's what you mean.

If the Admin form builds upon the ordinary form, you can use form inheritance.

```
class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

#Admin form inherits BaseForm
class AdminForm(BaseForm):
    occupation = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
```

If the two forms are sufficiently different, and do not share a meaningful common base, just create two distinct forms.

When you have the forms set up, have your views render one form or the other based on the user's parameters.

```
def createView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            form = AdminForm(request.POST)
        else:
            form = BaseForm(request.POST)
        ...
```